# group by , summarise by frequency R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group by data set based on some IDs, then leave the grouped data that has largest value in the column. Here is a description of my data set.

```
   BSTN ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN TRNID TRNID2 TRNID3 TRNID4 TRNID5 count
1   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1674      0      0      0      0     1
2   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1676      0      0      0      0     2
3   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1678      0      0      0      0     2
4   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1680      0      0      0      0    13
5   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1682      0      0      0      0     3
6   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1684      0      0      0      0     4
```

I want to group  and summarise this data into a single row based on IDs the first 10 columns **BSTN ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN**.
Then for the rest of the columns,  **TRNID TRNID2 TRNID3 TRNID4 TRNID5** I would like to replace them with the row with maximum value in column **count**.

What I want as my final output would look as below.

```
BSTN ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN TRNID TRNID2 TRNID3 TRNID4 TRNID5 count
 150   0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    152  1680     0      0      0      0    13
```

How would summarise my data? I have 2,931,959 rows with more groups of BSTN, ASTNs.

```
dput(head(A_Routetable2))
structure(list(BSTN = c(150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150), ASTN1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BSTN2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN2 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), BSTN3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN3 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), BSTN4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), BSTN5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN = c(152, 152, 152, 152, 
152, 152), TRNID = c(1674, 1676, 1678, 1680, 1682, 1684), TRNID2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TRNID3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TRNID4 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), TRNID5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), count = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 13L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    BSTN = c(150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150), ASTN1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), BSTN2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), BSTN3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN3 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), BSTN4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN4 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), BSTN5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ASTN = c(152, 152, 
    152, 152, 152, 152), TRNID = c(1674, 1676, 1678, 1680, 1682, 
    1684), TRNID2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TRNID3 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), TRNID4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group_by` position and then select row with max value in `count`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(across(1:10)) %>% slice(which.max(count))

#   BSTN ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN TRNID TRNID2 TRNID3 TRNID4 TRNID5 count
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
#1   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   152  1680      0      0      0      0    13
```

Or group by range of columns

```
df %>% group_by(across(BSTN:ASTN)) %>%slice(which.max(count))
```

---

The `dput` shared by OP is grouped which results an error with `across`. We can `ungroup` the data first and run the above which runs without any error. However functions in the previous version of `dplyr` work without any error on it. For example - `group_by_at`

```
A_Routetable2 %>% group_by_at(1:10) %>% slice(which.max(count))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak  for so much help, I remember that you have answered this problem before but I couldn't solve it yet.

Comment: A_Routetable2 %>% group_by(across(1:10)) %>% slice(which.max(count))
error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc. don't exist.
i There are only 2 columns.
i Input `..1` is `across(1:10)`.
i The error occured in group 1: BSTN = 150, ASTN1 = 0, BSTN2 = 0, ASTN2 = 0, BSTN3 = 0, ASTN3 = 0, BSTN4 = 0, ASTN4 = 0, BSTN5 = 0, ASTN = 152, TRNID = 1674, TRNID2 = 0, TRNID3 = 0, TRNID4 = 0.

Comment: @YunHyunsoo The error message states that you have only 2 columns in `A_Routetable2`. What is `ncol(A_Routetable2)` ? Are you sure you have the same data as shown? Maybe share your data with `dput(head(A_Routetable2))` ?

Comment: it is 16. The data described are first 6 columns of the original dataset

Comment: maybe it is because some groups of the IDs in BSTN~ASTN have the same "count"?

Comment: No, it does not matter if the `count` is same. This will select `max column for each group irrespective. Can you add data using `dput(head(A_Routetable2))` ?

Comment: I have added them in my edits thank you

Comment: @YunHyunsoo your data is already grouped, we need to ungroup it first so try `A_Routetable2 %>% ungroup %>% group_by(across(1:10)) %>% slice(which.max(count))` which works for your data.